# PDFBox appending a page to an existing PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to append a page(s) to the end of an existing PDF document.  I have searched and haven't found a conclusive answer.
I start out by checking if the pdf does not exist, or it is to be replaced.  If the existing pdf is to be appended,  I create PDDocument, loading the existing file. In the method "addImageAsNewPage",  I use the PDPageContentStream, with APPEND mode selected.

It appears that the contents of the pdf file are being overwritten, instead of being appended to the last page.  The pdf file has 2 pages prior trying to append.  After trying to append the pages,  I should have 4 pages in the document.

Does anyone have any ideas?  This seems like it should be straightforward, however, I find it somewhat counter-intuitive.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    public static void tiffToPdf(String j_source, String j_target,
        String j_replace, String message) {
        PDDocument doc = null;
        File target = new File(j_target);
        if (!replace || !target.exists()) {
           doc = new PDDocument();
        } else {
          doc = PDDocument.load(target);
        }

    for (BufferedImage image : extractedImages) {

        addImageAsNewPage(doc, image, replace);
    }
    doc.save(j_target);
    doc.close();

    private static void addImageAsNewPage(PDDocument doc, BufferedImage bufferedImage, boolean j_replace) throws Exception{

        PDImageXObject image          = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bufferedImage);
        PDRectangle    pageSize       = PDRectangle.A4;

        int            originalWidth  = image.getWidth();
        int            originalHeight = image.getHeight();
        float          pageWidth      = pageSize.getWidth();
        float          pageHeight     = pageSize.getHeight();
        float          ratio          = Math.min(pageWidth / originalWidth, pageHeight / originalHeight);
        float          scaledWidth    = originalWidth  * ratio;
        float          scaledHeight   = originalHeight * ratio;
        float          x              = (pageWidth  - scaledWidth ) / 2;
        float          y              = (pageHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

        PDPage         page           = new PDPage(pageSize);
        doc.addPage(page);
    if (j_replace) {
        try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc,
                page)) {
            contents.drawImage(image, x, y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        }
    } else {
        try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc,
                page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
            contents.drawImage(image, x, y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you verified thru debugging or tracing that the target pdf really exists? Your pdfbox code looks ok to me. Also check how often the loop is being used.

Comment: What is that `replace` variable you use in your `tiffToPdf` method? And what do you expect the effect of the value of `j_replace` in `addImageAsNewPage` to be? You are working with a freshly created page object, so it does not matter whether you create the `PDPageContentStream` in append mode or not...